# How can I install HP network printer in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8, printer, network-printer, hp-laserjet

I have an old HP LaserJet printer connected to the home LAN, which I would like to use over the Jet Direct protocol. How can I connect it to a Windows 8 device? Windows now seems to only allow to autodetect printers, and my one is not showing in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably not supported yet, you need to check with HP site for supported models...but if you want to by pass support here is the link hope this was helpful. http://www.wynapse.com/General/Windows8/Windows8Printers.aspx

Comment: The link doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the model, but the driver is almost certainly available from Microsoft, especially if the printer supports PCL5 or PostScript. Check the [Windows Compatibility Centre](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/compatibility/CompatCenter/Home?Language=en-AU).

If it is compatible, you can get the driver by clicking on the "Windows Update" button when asked for the printer model during the installation.

If Windows does not see the printer, try to install it as a **local** printer. When asked for the port, create a Standard TCP/IP port with the printer's IP address.

Comment: How do I install it as a local printer?

Comment: Go to Devices & Printers (if necessary, right-click the "Start" button, click Search and type Devices & Printers). Click "Add a Printer", then "The printer I want isn't listed" and "Add a Local Printer". Create the port and click Windows Update when asked for the model.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the drivers from the HP web site: http://h20331.www2.hp.com/hpsub/cache/343033-0-0-225-121.html?jumpid=ex_r2845_go/upd

And this solved all the problems.